# COIR + Compost as a simple/crude potting mix analog?

Tags: potting-soil

I am in a fairly unusual position of being able to get large quantities of bags of used coir at no cost from time-to-time.  Can anyone confirm if mixing coir + compost (home made) will make an OK'ish general purpose mix for a raised bed growing vegetables (like carrots, cucumbers, tomatoes, beans etc)?

For the sake of clarity, I'm a beginner here, so I'm trying to keep things simple - Right now is "works OK" and simple/generic is better for me then "ideal".   As I get more into things I will look at improvements.

Comment: "used" for what, coir?

Comment: Used to growing Zuchini and/or Tomato in a hothouse growing situation.

Comment: Coconut fiber is not high in nutrients, yet organic. Should keep the mix light, and free is a good price. You could still use some sand for grit and clay for minerals.

Comment: Mostly want to be aware of the potential for "phytosanitation" issues. *i.e.* beware of bringing home tomato blight, squash bug, or other pathogens.

Answer (score 1):

I think that would work okay.  I use a modified [soil block recipe from Penn State extension](https://extension.psu.edu/programs/master-gardener/counties/susquehanna/penn-state-master-gardener-articles/making-soil-blocks) for soil blocks, which was:

| Ingredient | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Peat / Coir | 8 qt. |
| Perlite | 5 qt. |
| Compost | 5 qt. |
| Garden Soil | 2qt. |
| 1-1-1 Fertilizer | 1 cup |
| Worm Castings | 1 cup |

Things are growing in it like gangbusters.  The perlite is there for density and aeration when I compress the block, so you could likely omit it in a potting mix.

As Ercnerwal said, you could be bringing in disease with coir from a hothouse.  It [can be sterilized](https://coir.com/growing-medium/how-to-sterilize-coco-coir/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20heat%2Dsterilize%20small,30%20minutes%20to%20kill%20pathogens.) by 30 minutes at 150°F/66°C.

Have you tried it?  How did it go?

Comment: Nothing to compare it to (im new to this) but filling my raised beds with coir and mixing in a layer of compost (1 bag per 1.25sqm) in the top few inches resulted in very happy looking curcubits and marigolds. Enough so that Im repeating tjis with another bed (or 2 if I can scrape together the wood)

Comment: @davidgo That's funny, I have some curcubits (luffa) growing in my soil blocks now.  Glad yours are growing well too.